# Are all proper subsets of $\mathbb R$ bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

My Real Analysis teacher published a problem set for midterm exam. I have encountered the following  question in it:

> Prove that if $A,B⊂\mathbb R$ then $\inf(A)+\inf(B) ≤ \inf(A+B)$

My question is, is every proper subset of $\mathbb R$ bounded? If the answer is yes, I can easily prove the following part. If the answer is no, how can I show $\inf(A)$ and $\inf(B)$ exists?

Comment: The set of integers is a proper subset of the real numbers, and it is, of course, not bounded.

Comment: If $A$ is bounded from below, then $\inf(A)$ exists. If $A$ is not bounded from below, you can define $\inf(A)=-\infty$ and $\inf(\emptyset)=+\infty$ With $r+(\pm\infty)=\pm\infty+r=\pm\infty$ and $-\infty<r<+\infty$, for all $r\in \mathbb{R}$ you still have the inequality. In the case that one of $A,B$ is empty and the other is unbounded from below, we would get $\pm\infty+(\mp\infty)$. We could define this as anything that is $<+\infty$ to make the inequality work. So, with the unbounded cases satisfied, by definition, it remains only to prove the bounded cases.

Comment: The negative reals are a proper subset

Comment: It is technically not true when $\inf A=-\infty$ and $B=\emptyset,$ because $\inf B=+\infty,$ and the left side doesn’t equal anything: $(-\infty)+(+\infty)$ is undefined. But it is true for non-empty $A,B.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every proper subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is bounded. For instance all the positive reals is not a bounded set, or for another example, $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{10\}$ is also unbounded. You've likely defined $\inf(A)$ for sets that are not bounded from below to be $-\infty$, but check this in your lecture notes.